# Any Load Testing Tool suggestion for the tests consists of Node.js using Selenium Web driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, load-testing, performance-testing, nodejs

We have a number of web pages that support and have a matching set of automated tests for those pages. Each test consists of node.js, using selenium web driver, and generally, we target a Chrome browser. Currently, we only perform one test at a time and would like to be able to load test so that the same test can be run simulating say 50 users at the same time and to run that for a few minutes.

Can anyone please suggest the good Load Testing tool supporting this requirement and framework set-up?

Comment: Which tools have you experiment so far and how did they fail do fulfill your needs?

Comment: Flood.io Load Testing, however, it doesn't support Flood Element using Selenium Web Driver. Any suggestions if you can provide?

Comment: Have you explored `Jmeter` or `k6`?

Comment: Why do you need Selenium for loading testing? Do your services act differently when interacting with a browser in comparison to another HTTP clients?

Comment: Hi @demouser123 - I have not yet tried JMeter or k6? Are both of the tools compatible and worth it to be used for Node.js framework set-up along with Selenium? Does JMeter support Javascript case scenarios?

Comment: Hi @JoãoFarias, Its not mandatory to use Selenium for Load Testing. I need a recommendation of the best supported tool which can be easy compatible for the Javascript based test scripts written through Node.js using Selenium Webdriver. And, our applications are all Web-based and chrome supported.

Comment: If you want to perform load testing, you want to investigate how your services behave under the usage of multiple users. My question is regarding all your points about browsers and Selenium, since browsers run on the client side, unaffected by services performance per se.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is going for [Selenium Grid](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/), running tests in parallel is one of its [main functionalities](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/purposes_and_main_functionalities/)

In general I would recommend using real browsers for load testing, there are no mentions of the memory requirements at the [Chrome system requirements page](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7100626?hl=en), however looking into [Firefox 75 system requirements](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/75.0/system-requirements/) it seems that you will need to have 1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM **per browser instance** so you would have to find the relevant amount of hardware somewhere somehow.

---

Be informed that browsers don't do any magic, they just send [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and render the responses, from the backend perspective it doesn't matter whether the HTTP Request comes from a browser or it's simulated on the protocol level by a load testing tool, assuming you [properly configure your load testing tool to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) you should be able to mimic 50 users using a couple of CPU cores and 1 GB of RAM.